# tcl: regexp match subsring at the end of string

Tags: regex, tcl

I trying to match a substring occurs many times in string

```
str1 = st1.st2.{k}.st3.{k}.st4.{k}.
str2 = st1.st2.{k}.st3.{k}.st4.
```

I use regexp to match `"{k}"` at the end of str1:

```
regexp .*\.\{k\}\.$ $str1
```

but I got 0 !!
in fact I use regsub to test the regexp

```
regsub {.*\.\{k\}\.$} $str {}
```

result ==> empty

if the pattern is matched, the matched string  will be removed !!
what missing in regexp expression ?

Comment: I'm not sure about TCL, but `{}` in general regex are special characters, so they need to be escaped (something like `\{k\}`). Could that be the case?

Comment: Please provide an example code that we can use to reproduce the issue you are having.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the `regexp` is returning the value 1 only, not 0.  When you want to match the last occurrence of `.{k}.`, you have to go ahead with sub-matches to get what you want.

```
set str1 st1.st2.{k}.st3.{k}.st4.{k}.
puts [regexp ".*(\.{k}\.)" $str1 whole last]
puts $last
```

**Output :**

```
1
.{k}.
```

The `$` sign is not mandatory to specify the end of line as we simply want to match the last occurrence.

With the `regsub`, you should be using the back-reference to capture the 1st group, so that it can be replaced correctly.

```
puts [regsub "(.*)(\.{k}\.)" $str1 "\\1"]
```

**Output :**

```
st1.st2.{k}.st3.{k}.st4
```

What is wrong with `regsub {.*\.\{k\}\.$} $str {}` ?

Well, the pattern `.*\.\{k\}\.$` will match the whole string and you are replacing it with empty string, which is why you are getting the empty result.

**Reference :** [Noncapturing Subpatterns](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/regexp81.tml#part2_7)